# Parse XML string as PHP Array?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp-2.0

I'm creating a RESTful webservice, right now I'm facing the insertion of the new resource (the `Season` resource). This is the body of the POST request:

```
<request>
   <Season>
      <title>new title</title>
   </Season>
</request>
```

and this is the controller that effectively perform the insertion:

```
public function add() {
    // i feel shame for this line
    $request = json_decode(json_encode((array) simplexml_load_string($this->request->input())), 1);

    if (!empty($request)) {
        $obj = compact("request");
        if ($this->Season->save($obj['request'])) {
            $output['status'] = Configure::read('WS_SUCCESS');
            $output['message'] = 'OK';
        } else {
            $output['status'] = Configure::read('WS_GENERIC_ERROR');
            $output['message'] = 'KO';
        }
        $this->set('output', $output);
    }
    $this->render('generic_response');
}
```

The code works pretty well, but as I wrote in the snippet above I consider the first line of the controller really ugly, so, the question is: How can I parse XML string as PHP Array?

Comment: `xml_parse_into_struct()`

Comment: Why do you have `compact("request")` then `$obj['request']`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me, try it;

```
<request>
   <Season>
      <title>new title</title>
   </Season>
   <Season>
      <title>new title 2</title>
   </Season>
</request>
```

.

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("xml.xml");
// print_r($xml);
$xml_array = array();
foreach ($xml as $x) {
    $xml_array[]['title'] = (string) $x->title;
    // or 
    // $xml_array['title'][] = (string) $x->title;
}
print_r($xml_array);
```

Result;

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [Season] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => new title
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [title] => new title 2
                )

        )

)
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [title] => new title
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [title] => new title 2
        )

)
// or
Array
(
    [title] => Array
        (
            [0] => new title
            [1] => new title 2
        )

)
```